# Is there a device to plug in to dead socket to figure out which breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

First, I do have an entire house shutoff which is very nice to swap out breakers.

I have installed breakers for the bathroom but recently a breaker or something tripped while I was using a circular saw on an outdoor socket and my basement is also out(hmmmm, not sure those were on the same breaker....I will have to think about that which is odd considering I am the original owner of the house so that would be a builder that perhaps messed up there).

EDIT: **All breakers say on while the socket is dead so I am assuming a breaker is broken** so it's not the normal tripped where I just reset it.

Anyways, is there a device to detect the breaker for a socket?    Do I have to tap the wires instead(ie. shutoff the entire house while I tap each wire behind the panel that seals the wires away).

Any ideas here on how to proceed here?  link to amazon device perhaps?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: You are looking for a breaker finder or circuit breaker finder.  Any search will give you what you need.  Quite a few of them to choose from.

Comment: @crip659 Just make sure it is UL or ETL listed. The "link to Amazon device" leaves open the possibility of dangerous junk.

Comment: There could be a subpanel hiding somewhere.

Comment: If you were using an exterior device, it is likely you tripped a GFCI outlet, not a breaker at your panel.

Answer (score 11):

What you need with a dead circuit is a toner tracer.

Most circuit breaker finders are line powered the transmitter with a battery powered receiver that picks up the tone, yes these need to be UL or NRTL listed.

reality for a dead circuit is that a toner tracer is needed

A toner tracer is a low voltage battery operated device pair that do not require listing.

Most will not work with live circuits, placing a toner on the normally hot and neutral will be able to trace the wires to the breaker while the power is turned off

So get a toner tracer for under 30$ that will work on dead or low voltage (telephone) circuits, the more expensive ones up to ~1K$ that can function on live circuits need to be listed but for DIY a dead circuit is a safe way to go and less expensive.

Comment: Truth is, I've never really had the problem (small house and almost everything pretty well labeled on a diagram. But I never thought of "if a receptacle is dead, just use an ordinary toner/tracer" - as I have (and use often enough) one of those for phone & network use. Good to know I can use that as long as the circuit is currently dead! Just need to remember *not* to flip the breaker until after removing the toner...could be exciting otherwise.

Comment: At least in the circuit-breaker finder device for which I did the programming, what is transmitted isn't a "tone", but rather a periodic brief current spike.  This causes the breaker to periodically produce a magnetic field pulse which the device can detect.  For a device to operate on an open circuit, it must output a voltage-based signal that would cause attached wiring to emit a changing electric field, requiring a completely different receiver.

Comment: @supercat , what are you talking about? A toner tracer produces an oscillating frequency, weather we can hear it or not is irrelevant, once the signal is decoded the tracer provides a audio or visual signal   The signal that is placed on the line has a unique signal that is detectable by the tracer. The greenlee cs8000 may not be able to be heard but works the same way although not audible

Comment: @EdBeal: My point was that devices designed for use on live circuits operate on fundamentally different principles from those designed for use on open circuits.  As someone involved with the design of a live-circuit device, I know that the receiver design is fundamentally incompatible with any kind of transmitter that could work on an open circuit.

Comment: @supercat again you are wrong I actually own a model that works fine open circuit closed live or dead. it is not a cheap unit like the models that have limitations similar to the unit you worked on. I have several different types of toners and several different circuit breaker finders, the ones I have checked with a scope to see if I could make them more sensitive we’re simple oscillator’s that we’re coupled on the ac and the receiver filtered out the 60hz and found the frequency some pick the strongest signal , some are adjustable and use the operator to pick the strongest signal others auto

Comment: @EdBeal: There may be devices that are designed for use on open-circuits that will also work fine on live circuits, but devices which are only required to work on live circuits can be designed more simply than those which have to work on open circuits, and I would expect that most devices that are designed for use on live circuits work in that fashion, especially since the way circuit breakers are constructed (at least the ones I've examined) makes current-based signalling very effective.  Not sure how panel-mound AFCI or GFCI devices are built, and whether they would work well with the them.

Comment: Supercat the devices are not current based I have explained how they work maybe you should learn about more than one and offer an answer as this is not a discussion site but a question answer format.

Comment: @EdBeal: As a contract engineer who was intimately involved with the design of one such device which to my knowledge is still on the market, I know how that device, and OEM-packaged variations, works.  It detects changes in current.  I would be only mildly surprised if the client has enforced patents against anyone else who tried to use a current-based approach, causing every other product on the market to use a voltage-based one instead, but if you haven't seen any current-based designs, you haven't examined all circuit-finder devices.

Comment: Supercat as I said current would not work in the real world because an open circuit has no current. But you are free to post the brand and model as one you have experienced.  as discussion are not what this forum is about.

Comment: @EdBeal: My whole point, which maybe I failed to make clear, was that the device I was involved with was only designed for use on live circuits, and *would not be adaptable for use on open circuits*.  If your claim is that no devices which can work on open circuits can use current, then we're in vociferous agreement.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you've identified the breaker that connects to the dead socket, which should be the one that tripped. You can use a [circuit breaker finder](https://www.protoolreviews.com/how-circuit-breaker-finders-work/), however these only work on live circuits. That means you should still create a map of your electrical system, which you can also do in a simpler fashion.

This is something I do once in every new house:

1. draw rudimentary maps of each floor (you can use floor plans as a basis to get the width/height more or less right)
2. mark down socket, switch and light fixture locations on these maps
3. number the breakers (for example top to bottom and left to right, and/or by residual current circuit breaker or group, for example A1, A2, A3, B4, B5, B6)
4. switch off one breaker at a time
5. mark the breaker number at each light fixture / switch / socket that's affected

You can use a couple of light fixtures (switched to the on setting) as detectors. If something never switches to on, it may need repairs.

I always start out with pen and paper, but because I'm not the only one that has to understand these, I decided to draw them out (in this case in Illustrator, this is a sample):

[image]

This is the third time I've done so (and I have an architectural background), so the example above is probably a bit more detailed and proportionally correct than necessary. But you get the idea. I'm not using electrical symbols, but rather something that anyone in the house can easily interpret. I've pasted a printed version on the inside of the fuse box door.

[image]

This would correspond to the physical fuse box layout, so it's easy to see where the groups are.

[image]

In this latest iteration I've also added a list of what's connected to which group, so I know what I can turn off safely (and what would cause the WiFi to turn off, or the freezer to thaw). Here, red is critical stuff, blue is important/convenient to have stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a break in the circuit, not a broken breaker.

1. Do you know any sockets that were on this breaker? Are they also dead?
   If some of them work and rest doesn't, search for a burned wire between last working and first non-working socket.
2. If you have a power shutoff for the panel, and are comfortable working on it, swap live wire from the "broken" breaker and connect it to known working breaker near it. Turn on the power.
   If the sockets come to life, it was a bad breaker. If the breaker trips, there is an fault in the circuit. If nothing happens, but sockets still don't have power, then the feeder wire from panel to first socket is bust.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect it's a breaker, then I suggest starting with a simple test of elimination. You can do it right now - find something controlled by each breaker and try turning that breaker on and off, and see if the thing also turned off. This way you can eliminate each breaker in turn from being the defective one. If you find a breaker that seemingly controls nothing, then it's likely your culprit. Just don't forget to consider devices that aren't glaringly obviously on or off, like boilers or floor heaters or whatever.

If all breakers seem to work fine, then either there are some breakers you don't know about, or the fault is elsewhere. Have you tried opening up the socket itself? A bad/rusted contact in there could have overheated and burned out without being visible from outside. And since it's on the outside, the smell would have been masked too.